# Right alignment in Form elements wrong

Tags: html, css, forms, sass

I have a problem that I believe might be pretty stupid, but I can't figure out. 
I have a form, where I want to align the elements in both sides, problem is I can't align it to the right (where the red line is), here is a picture to show it:

[image: form alignment wrong]

and here is my SASS (sorry if is not very tidy I been working for a while in it and might be messy):

```
.contact {
margin: 100px auto 0;
max-width: $half-width;
form {
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    color: $color4;
    input, textarea {
        border: 3px solid $color5;
        padding: 10px;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
        font-size: 16px;
        background: $color6;
        &:focus {
            outline: none !important;
            border-color: $color3 !important;
        }
        textarea {
            height: 10em;
            width: 100%;
            overflow: inherit;
        }
    }
    .info-group {
        margin-top: 10px;
        label {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 45%;
            float: left;
            &:nth-child(2) {
                float: right !important;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }
        }
    }
    .tell-group {
        width: 100%;
        label {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
        textarea {
            height: 10em;
            width: 100%;
            float: left;
        }
    }
    .submit-wrap {
        margin-top: 10px;
        float: right;
        input {
            width: 100px;
            font-size: 18px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            color: $color6;
            background-color: $color5;
            border: none;
            &:hover {
                color: $color1;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: go to your console/developer tool, and target the desired element. it will show you any `padding/margin` that is affecting the element. remove it accordingly.  you are prob using some frame work that have pre-define style.

Comment: just a quick way to test use `*{padding:0 !important; margin:0 !important;}` at the beginning of your style sheet see what changes.

Comment: If you have a pure CSS problem, we don't need the Sass.  You need to provide the *smallest* amount of code necessary to reproduce the problem (no markup, waaay too much CSS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`padding: 10px;` is going to add 20px to the width, this extra width is likely what is causing the problem.  You can change the width attribute to `width: calc(100% - 20px);` to account for the 10px padding on each side of the element.

Here is a list of where calc is supported: http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

You can also try adding these css rules to the problem elements to move them over:

```
position: relative;
left: -20px;
```

You might also have to add `position: relative;` to the parent element

Here is a fiddle showing the `left -20px` method: http://jsfiddle.net/0f153w8e/

Side note: you might have to adjust the `left` amount a little bit to make it exact if your text areas have borders (which they probably do)

Comment: Calc has worse support than box-sizing.  A top/right/bottom/left of 0 on a relatively positioned element won't do anything unless it is overriding a previously declared value.

Comment: Edited to `left: -20px`, not sure why I was thinking the 0px would do anything, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Thank you Joe, your solution work for the 2 first boxes, although the only way to align the send button was just adding a 'margin-right:-6px', could it be related with the border?

Comment: It looked like the send button in your picture was already aligned, but that could be due to padding or border, not sure. You could also apply the `left` attribute here instead of `margin-right`, but it shouldn't matter too much. I just want you to know that this is kind of a quick fix for difficult situations and you should always try to get stuff to align correctly without using `left` or `margin` before resorting to that method. Try pressing f12 in your browser to open the DOM editor where you can add and remove attributes quickly to see their effect, it can be very helpful